# How to fix partial intellisense for dotnetcore rtm in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I only have partial intellisense in Visual Studio 2015 for dotnetcore 1.0

Projects are properly referenced and build fine. I am using Resharper.

[image: Intellisense only partially functioning]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

REsharper is currently not supporting dotnet core. Suspend it in Tools > options > REsharper.

EDIT:
I have confirmed EAP 6 fixes this. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+2016.2+EAP

Comment: @MIke I have confirmed EAP 6 fixes this.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+2016.2+EAP

Comment: Woot awesome! Can't wait for resharper to support dotnetcore So i don't have to turn it off.

Comment: Check the link @MIke, it fixes it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install ReSharper 2016.2 (currently in EAP) to get support for .net core. 1.0 RTM is supported from EAP6 onwards.